# Configuring environment variable based on client in NodeJS

Tags: architecture, node-modules

Currently we are using the NodeJS at server side for our SaaS application.Using REST API's, clients(Web + Android + iOS) connect to NodeJS application.

The Nodejs application has a router file(acting as a configuration file) which declares global variables to connect with DB, Redis and AWS, as shown below.

[image]

Now one of our clients wants their DB to be in private, which means not to be shared with other client data. In other words, this tenant don't want to stay with other tenants. Just think of this client as tenant "L" as shown below.While the NodeJS app remains same, the data for client "L" will be stored in different server.

**I need help** from the Stackoverflow community on how I can achieve/set different global variables based on client request. How I can configure & load global variables based on client request. Or what are the other possible ways to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: How are you loading this configuration file?

Comment: Config variables are declared in the router file. I believe they are loaded when the node server is getting started.

Comment: For the clients that want their own database, just make them a database, and connect to it with another mysql.createPool.

Answer (score 0):

@Da-jin his problem is global vars so needs identify when to use which pool. I would suggest @Vikram to create a wrapper or middleware which would return a config object or identifier which will help you to decide when to use which config as soon as you receive a request. Again in any of the case there are changes required.

Or a simple solution I would suggest is create global config object like:

```
config = { 
    shared: {
         mysqlPool : sharedMySqlPoolObj, 
         redisPool: sharedRedispoolObj
 },
 tenantT: {
        mysqlPool : tMySqlpoolObj,
        redispool: tRedispoolObj
  }
}
```

And wherever you are doing db or redis connection 
Just replace your code with following:

For example if your doing my sql connection

```
 let clientType = getClientType() // shared or tenantT

globalConfig[clientType].mysqlPool.connect(.....);
```

May be it can help and save you from making major changes

Comment: Thank you, Dhiraj for your response. The problem is across the Node application the global variable is getting used to get the MYSQL connection. I was looking at a way where the global variable is set based on the client, but I guess I am approaching it in wrong way as NodeJS is stateless in nature.

Comment: Correct that's why I provided you the solution which would get config on the fly. You will have to make it dynamic in order to work but that would be one time change and in future you can maintain app for multiple clients with private pool.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this up